# Pause\Stop background video

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть кнопка, по клику на которую - я останавливаю фоновое видео, помогите дописать, чтобы на повторный клик, видео заново воспроизводилось.

```
 $('.pause-video').click(function(){
   $('#VidageVideo').get(0).pause();
 });
```

Comment: лучше всего было бы выяснить, как узнать, проигрывается ли видео в настоящий момент? есть такой функционал у вашего плеера?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первое - это обработчик события клика - `click`, переделайте, чтобы он срабатывал, когда вы кликаете по элементу `video`, у вас обработчик сейчас на классе `.pause-video`, ну если он сработает и после повтороного нажатия, то ладно.

Ну и далее, у видео есть как метод `pause()`, так и метод `play()`. Для проверки, стоит ли пауза на видео, можно использовать свойство `paused` у видео.

```
$('.pause-video').click(function() {
  var video = $('#VidageVideo').get(0);
  if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
  } else {
    video.pause();
  }
});
```

В принципе это все, для вашего примера должно быть достаточно, а именно:

- Метод `play()` - начинает воспроизведение аудио/видео.
- Метод `pause()` - приостанавливает воспроизведение аудио/видео в данный момент.
- Свойство `paused` - возвращает, приостановлено ли аудио/видео или нет.

Ну и ссылка на небольшой пример (увы, тут нельзя загрузить видео в сниппет): [**пример**](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_av_met_play_pause).

Comment: Спасибо вам большое